# Is America really a corporation?

Tags: parties, political-system, corporations

I have read several articles and websites that have stated that America is actually a corporation... But I don't think this is true since we have so many rights and freedom.

Is America really a corporation?

Comment: Unless you give some objective criteria by which one would consider it a corporation or not, this question is unanswerable.

Comment: The definition of "corporation" is so broad that, yes, I suppose you could say that. But you could, in a sense, say the same about Al-Qaeda or even a family carrying out a yard sale. This question is answerable but pointless.

Answer (score 2):

Let's have a look at the definition of "Corporation"

[corporation](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/corporation?s=t):

> noun
>
> 1. **an association of individuals, created by law or under authority of law, having a continuous existence independent of the existences of its members, and powers and liabilities distinct from those of its members. See also municipal corporation, public corporation.**
> 2. (initial capital letter) the group of principal officials of a borough or other municipal division in England.
> 3. **any group of persons united or regarded as united in one body.**
> 4. Informal. a paunch; potbelly.

I think that the US matches definition 1 and definition 3.

Comment: That's definitions 1 and 3, not 2.

Comment: Also, the US really doesn't meet definition 1 - it wasn't created by a law (the constitution was more like a bylaw; "created by law" implies that there was an external law creating it)

Comment: I need to lay off these girl scout cookies. I'm getting a corporation.

Comment: @DA. - http://www.girlscouts.org/who_we_are/our_partners/corporations_foundations/.